# Nvidia GPU fans doesn't change accordingly to temperature

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, gpu, fan

I've been strungling for a while trying all the possible drivers to have an RTX 3060 and a 4060 ti working in linux. The 'ubuntu-drivers autoinsall' uses the 535 driver, which does not detect the 4060 ti properly.
I've tested also the propietary drivers currently downloadable from Nvidia. The current driver is the 550, and it is a pain in the ass to install it. Even that,the 4060 ti is detected but the fans are not working properly neither.

So I ended using the 'sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550' directly. Which detects both gpu (the glmark2 seems to perform ok) but, still the same thing with fans: they are not chaging accordingly to thermal or power consumption.

My linux distribution is Ubuntu 22.04.

This is how it looks right now:
[image]

[image]

[image]

If I do not enable the GPU Fan Settings, the fans doesn't work at all, no matter the temperature.

Does anyone knows how can I correct this behaviour?

**Update 1/4/2024**

Moreover, the settings are not saved and I have to reset the fan speed everytime after rebooting:

```
sudo nvidia-settings -a GPUFanControlState=1 -a GPUTargetFanSpeed=30
```

Comment: Just to be clear, by working properly, you want them to change according to the  Thermal Settings in the GPU fan settings, correct? Edit the question and add the release of Ubuntu that you are using.